# How to refactor a project with renaming categories in Xcode 5?

Tags: refactoring, xcode5, objective-c-category

Is it possible with xcode 5 to refactor the name of a category and making sure every instance where its imported is also renamed? I have tried right clicking and refactor->rename on the name, but it does not recognize where its used and does not change file name.

Comment: This is rather strange that this does not work. In general the renaming in xcode works rather well.